# Add a new address during multishipping checkout

Tags: checkout, forms, address, array, multishipping

Is there a good way to allow users to add new addresses during multishipping checkout in-page (not having to go to a dedicated form page) the way many onepage checkouts function?

Answer (score 2):

The multi-address checkout just isnt designed this way. Its a much neglected part of Magento, and if you go thro the code you can see why they didnt do the add address part, its awful codebase.

I've worked on this code in the past and I'd say if you can get away without putting this in then do so.